# how to insert column data as a list of list in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of list like

```
a = [[1,2],[2,3]]
```

my dataframe is like this:

```
        name 
0       John
1       Mike
```

i want to insert this list of lists to a new column called 'Score' like this:

```
        name    Score
0       John    [[1,2],[2,3]]
1       Mike    [[1,2],[2,3]]
```

I tried doing this:

```
df['Score'] = 0
df['Score'] = df['Score'].astype(object)
```

Now setting directly

```
df['Score'] = a
```

gives error.Then i tried using

```
df.at[1,'Score'] = a
```

This works but for only row =1 but i want to set all the rows of that column = a.So i tried .loc

```
df.loc[:,'Score'] = a
```

but it didnt help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
a = [[1,2],[2,3]]
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['John', 'Mike']})

df['score'] = [a for _ in range(df.shape[0])]
```

Output:

```
   name             score
0  John  [[1, 2], [2, 3]]
1  Mike  [[1, 2], [2, 3]]
```